My workplace is turning my role from a contractor into an employee with a significant pay cut. Is that normal?
I work for a startup and they have applied for a grant that would cover part of my salary an employee. I'm a contractor right now making $38.50/hour (which works out to about $75k/year).
Starting next month, they want to move me into an employee role and put me on a salary of $65k/year. When I asked about this, my boss said that it is normal for employees to make less than contractors.
I should add that this is a startup and the employee job wont come with any healthcare, RRSP matching, or other benefits. It is also a short-term role because I am going back to part time in 5 months to start a practicum for my Master's and he said he wants me to go back to being a contractor at that time. I also doubt I will get any paid vacation.
This seems like an overall loss for me. Am I missing something?

Edited:  The issue is the grant they are receiving only covers employees, not contractors.

Are you comparing apples to apples, with regard to taxes, do you receive a W2 today (or an equivalent outside the states) as a contractor today? If you are a contractor then you don’t have any vacation outside what’s been defined in the contract, which probably isn’t very much, unless you work for a company that provides vacation time

Country tag would help here. You need to to the "apples to apples" math. It really depends a lot on the difference between benefits for employees and contractors for your specific contract and local laws. and what exactly is covered by the "hourly rate" On first blush this sounds like a great deal: my contractor rate is about 3 times higher than my employee nominal rate was.

RRSP would suggest Canada, but then it'd also vary by industry, province/territory and potentially nation

with neither benefits nor job security (most startups don't last), it's unclear what the appeal is

I suspect the "not any benefits" is not quite true; as an employee, you'll be entitled to a bunch of benefits by law, and rights and protections. This depends on your country (and state / province within the country, industry, size of company...), but may include things like paid public holidays, various forms of paid or unpaid leave for reasons from sickness to jury duty, possibly pro-rata annual leave, protections against dismissal, pension contributions, etc.
Whether these are worth $10k/year... probably?
A $38.50/hour contract rate converting to $65k/year doesn't sound unreasonable in its own right, and may well be effectively a raise.
Of course, that doesn't rule out your employer trying to pull a fast one. It also doesn't rule out you negotiating more, although I'm guessing your BATNA is "not working for 5 months", so that's not great negotiating leverage.
Overall, it doesn't raise any red flags, except:

he wants me to go back to being a contractor at that time

That's probably something to discuss with someone familiar with the local labour law; unless you agree to it in advance (and perhaps even then), the employer may be quite restricted in how they can turn you back into a contractor. It's also the kind of thing where you want someone actually locally experienced to advise on exact wording of the clause, not the Internet and not the employer's lawyer.
If the $65k/year is a raise (or being presented as a raise), you don't want a guaranteed pay cut after the 5 months.
Even if you plan to leave in 5 months, it may be worthwhile to leave that open, in case your plans change, perhaps due to events outside your control.

The OP clearly wrote "I should add that this is a startup and the employee job wont come with any healthcare, RRSP matching, or other benefits."  --- So, are you saying the OP does not understand her own company policy or she is not telling the truth when you wrote "I suspect the "not any benefits" is not quite true"?

@Job_September_2020 Yeah, there seems to be a misunderstanding somewhere, perhaps caused by overly summarising along the chain of communication, or the boss may have incentive to de-emphasise some of the benefits

In the US, even just the employer share of SS+Medicare is worth a 7.65% difference.

As a contractor they're paying you about $75k/year. They pay for no healthcare benefits, retirement plan contributions, PTO, vacation, etc. That $75k/year is your "total compensation package" and is their total cost to "employ" you.
As an employee they want to pay you a salary of $65k a year. An employer would generally have additional costs to employ you. Things like healthcare benefits, retirement plan contributions, PTO, vacation, etc. All of this combined would ultimately be considered your "total compensation package". In addition they have additional costs such as payroll taxes, workers compensation costs, etc. In this scenario, their total cost to "employ" you would likely be more than the $75k/year they pay you as a contractor. All of this means that your salary as an employee will generally be lower than what your hourly rate as a contractor would be.
If they're not offering any benefits, PTO, vacation time, retirement plan, etc. then ask what the justification for the lower salary is.
If they can't justify the lower salary with actual facts and figures then negotiate for a higher salary. At the end of the day, they can't do anything unless you go along with it. They don't own you. You're free to walk away any time you so choose.

Presumably they are offering at least the mandatory employee benefits, whatever those are in the jurisdiction

Payroll tax is a big one.


Is that normal?

No. It is not normal.
It is only normal if they pay for the employees' other benefits such as health insurance, 401K, stock options, vacation, PTO, unemployment benefits, etc...


This seems like an overall loss for me. Am I missing something?

I agree that this is an overall loss.

I am not sure where you are located.
Also, I am not sure if your company pays for the unemployment benefits of full-time employees.
But, the following applies to the US companies:
In many cases, if a company needs to let go someone due to the loss of profit, they usually let go contractors first before laying off full-time employees. The reason is that if they lay off the employees, they may have to contribute the unemployment benefits for those employees (Again, this is true for the US).
Here is the law in Texas (USA):
Employers pay unemployment insurance taxes and reimbursements, which support unemployment benefit payments.
Here is the full link (for Texas, USA).


When I asked about this, my boss said that it is normal for employees to make less than contractors.

Haha...  I guess that your boss was trying to be funny when hiding the fact that you won't get other benefits. :-)
It is true that generally, full-time employees have less salary than contractors. But, for most companies, full-time employees get other benefits such as health insurance, 401K, stock options, etc... that contractors don't. Those benefits may balance out the loss of salary for employees.
As you wrote, your boss won't pay for those benefits for employees.

The issue is the grant they are receiving only covers employees, not contractors.

@AnnieMacintosh, So, without this grant, does it mean they have to lay off you because they don't have money to pay you ?  --- How did they have the money to pay you as a contractor up to this point ? Why can't they continue to pay you as a contractor, and they have to force you to convert to an employee now ?

It is normal for employee to make less "Gross Pay" than contractors, but it isn't an Apples to Apples comparison.
There is no benefit for you to switch to an employee for 5 months.
Ask them for a list of the benefits. Items like insurance, taxes, retirement, etc. will count for a large amount of the difference.
BUT THERE IS NO INSURANCE AND RETIREMENT. And you won't be there long enough for a vacation.
It is a different case for a contractor that becomes a fulltime employee with benefits and is expected to remain for the long haul. But that isn't you.
I own a business, I don't get their logic.
UPDATE:
Your edit made all the difference in the world! :)
The want to cover you with the grant. Clear and simple.

"you won't be there long enough for a vacation" - long enough to accrue a few days of PTO plus public holidays; similarly for retirement etc
